# Is it possible to verify the components' size of non-color-renderable internal format?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

In OpenGL ES 3.0 spec we can read:

> § 4.4.5
>
> When the relevant framebuffer binding is non-zero, if the currently bound
> framebuffer object is not framebuffer complete, then the values of the state variables
> listed in table 6.34 are undefined.

Table 6.34 contains the `x_BITS` constant. That means we can create a texture or renderbuffer that's not color-renderable, but we can't verify that it has proper size.

Is there any way around this, or is my idea completely skewed and this information is irrelevant (which would render the question incorrect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query a bound render buffer properties using GetRenderbufferParameteriv (6.1.14 Renderbuffer Object Queries). For example with RENDERBUFFER_-
INTERNAL_FORMAT.

The problem is that unless the framebuffer is complete, it is not well formed thus the specification just states that values returned are undefined. That's doesn't mean you can query for one of the renderbuffers attached and get the desired information.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I forgot ES also has `GetRenderbufferParameter`. The section doesn't state what happens when such a call is made to incomplete buffer, though. However, the very next section, *4.15 - Internal Format Queries* has that sentence about `GetInternalformativ` : "internalformat must be color-renderable, depth-renderable or stencilrenderable(as defined in section 4.4.4).". That would suggest the futility of my attempts, no?

Comment: You get an GL_INVALID_ENUM​ error if you try to create a render buffer and internalformat​ is not a color-renderable, depth-renderable, or stencil-renderable format.

Comment: In fact you state in your question that you can create a non-renderable render buffer object and that is not correct. Didn't notice that before.